# UI issue in Progress Bar animation

Tags: user-interface, animation, qml

I'm developing a progress bar in QML.

But the working is not working for all parameter values. 
Its more bit of logical issue in UI

Requesting everyone to review it.

below is the code snippet

```
Rectangle
{
    width: 500; height: 480

    .....

    color: "lightyellow"

    Rectangle {
        id: container
        ....

        Row {
            id:repeaterid


            Repeater {
                id: repeater
                model: 100
                Item { id: smallrect2; opacity:0.5; width:_width; height:_height

                    Rectangle { id: smallrect; color: _newColor }

                 ......  

                }
            }
        }

        Timer {
            id: progressTimer
            interval: 100

            onTriggered: {

                if ((slider.x + slider.width) < repeaterid.width)
                {
                    slider.x += _width
                    var item = repeater.itemAt(indexCurrent)
                    item._newColor = "red"
                    indexCurrent++
                }
                else
                {
                    progressTimer.repeat = false
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: slider

            // Adjust the dimensions of slider
            x: repeaterid.x 
            y: repeaterid.y
            width: _width 
            height: _height 

        }
    }

}
```

The desired behaviour is achieved when value of _width is 30 and the model value in the repeater is 18, but as the value is decreased the slider in progress bar doesn't complete its path ( width = 5, model =100 ) or if increased it moves out of the path.

Comment: The issue lies in if condition in the timer, but still not able to crack the proper condition for the slider

Comment: Just a note: creating the dots with the Repeater is really bad for performance. You are creating (and rendering) at least 200 separate elements and 300 property bindings. This will slow down the creating  part of loading the scene considerably. Also rendering will be unnecessarily slow. I would suggest creating an png image with the dot and some transparent pixels on the left. Then make an Image element use that with the fillMode set to Image.Tile and adjust the width of the Image element to reveal more dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : Adjusted model value according to container size & rectangle size